# mysql.connector のインポートエラー解消方法を教えていただきたい

Tags: python, mysql

現在MySQLを独学で学んでおります。

以下詳細記載のステップ1〜4を実行したのですが、
ステップ4(2)のDB-APIの設定においてエラーが出て躓いております。

ステップ1でmysqlはインポートされていると思うのですが、
エラー原因についてご教授いただきたいです。

ステップ1
mysqlのインストール

```
(base) sugimotoyuuki@sugimotoyuukinoMacBook-Air-2 webapp % sudo -H python3 setup.py install
Password:
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing vsearch.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to vsearch.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to vsearch.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'vsearch.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'vsearch.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg
copying build/lib/vsearch.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/vsearch.py to vsearch.cpython-37.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying vsearch.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying vsearch.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying vsearch.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying vsearch.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/vsearch-1.0-py3.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing vsearch-1.0-py3.7.egg
Removing /Users/sugimotoyuuki/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vsearch-1.0-py3.7.egg
Copying vsearch-1.0-py3.7.egg to /Users/sugimotoyuuki/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
vsearch 1.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /Users/sugimotoyuuki/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vsearch-1.0-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for vsearch==1.0
Finished processing dependencies for vsearch==1.0
```

ステップ2
mysql python driverのインストール

```
mysql -u root -p

mysql> create user 'vsearch' identified by 'vsearchpasswd';
mysql> grant all on vsearchlogDB.* to 'vsearch';
```

ステップ3
databaseとtablesの作成

テーブル用コードを作成後、以下がoutputとして表示される

describe log;

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id             | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| ts             | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| phrase         | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| letters        | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| ip             | varchar(16)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| browser_string | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| results        | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

ステップ4　
DB-APIの設定

(1)
connection characterristicsの定義

```
>>> dbconfig = {'host': '127.0.0.1',
                'user': 'vsearch',
                'password': 'vsearchpasswd',
                'database': 'vsearchlogDB',}
```

(2)
database driverのインポート ※ここで躓いてます

```
>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ステップ1 やステップ2 の「説明」と「実際の作業内容」とで理解が食い違っているように見えます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python から MySQL に接続するための "MySQL Connector" をインストールしたいということであれば、下記の通り `pip` コマンドでインストールするのが一番簡単そうです。

[MySQL Connector/Python Developer Guide :: 4.2 Installing Connector/Python from a Binary Distribution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html)

> #### Installing Connector/Python with pip
>
> Use **pip** to install Connector/Python on most any operating system:
>
> ```
> shell> pip install mysql-connector-python
> ```